# Aggregate function calls may not be nested ERROR

Tags: sql, t-sql, postgresql, netezza

I am trying to run this query in postgresql but getting this error: "ERROR:  Aggregate function calls may not be nested".  I am not sure what the problem or a solution for this.

Here is my query:

```
select a.KEY_NBR, a.MAIN_ID
        , 
            case
                when a.KEY_NBR = a.MAIN_ID
                    then 'Don''t Use'
                when a.count = MAX(a.count) over(partition by a.KEY_NBR)
                    then 'Good'
                else 'Bad'
            end [flag]
    from MYTABLE a
```

Comment: `MAX` is an aggregate function, and you might want the result of `MAX(a.count)` to be returned by a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? Tested similar query in 9.2 - it worked ok.

Comment: I am actually using Workbench: Aginity Workbench for Netezza 4.0.998.20231 and it uses postgresql

Comment: Show output for `select version()` query then.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks ok and should work. Perhaps the version you use has some limitations. Try this variation:

```
WITH a AS
  ( SELECT key_nbr, main_id, count,
           MAX(count) OVER (PARTITION BY key_nbr) AS max_count
    FROM mytable
  ) 
SELECT a.key_nbr, a.main_id,
       CASE WHEN a.key_nbr = a.main_id
                THEN 'Don''t Use'
            WHEN a.count = max_count 
                THEN 'Good'
            ELSE 'Bad'
       END AS flag
FROM a ;
```

Comment: You don't have a column named `count`? Your code indicates that you do have.